# Kotlin data classes contains open functions

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I was reading kotlin official tutorial, Under the [data class topic](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html), I came up with a following point.

> If a supertype has the componentN() functions that are open and return compatible types, the corresponding functions are generated for the data class and override those of the supertype. If the functions of the supertype cannot be overridden due to incompatible signatures or being final, an error is reported;

My Questions are,

1) What is `componentN()` functions ?

2) Does the data class override the open function automatically ?

3) Is following code correct ?

```
open class SuperDataClass {

  open fun componentN() {
     println("from super class")
  }
}

data class DataClassExample (var name: String): SuperDataClass() {
  //
}
```

Comment: There is a link to an explanation of `componentN` literally in the first mention of `componentN` in the docs you linked to :/

Comment: Banging my head. Yes i just saw the link.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What is componentN() functions ?

They are operator functions corresponding to the properties in their order of declaration.

Example:

```
 data class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

the class above will have a `component1` and a `component2` function, allowing the [access through destructuring declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) to name and age, in that order.
Take in consideration that `componentN` function is just to reference 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ..., Nth component. The `componentN` function itself is never generated.

> 2) Does the data class override the open function automatically ?

In data class, you are extending from `Any` class, you aren't overriding automatically any function. `componentN` functions are generated at compile time.

> 3) Is following code correct ?

```
open class SuperDataClass {
    open fun componentN() {
        println("from super class")
    }
}

data class DataClassExample (var name: String): SuperDataClass() {
    //
}
```

Yes, it will compile and will run correctly. But this is only because, as I said before, `componentN` isn't generated for data classes.
 However, in this case a `component1` is generated for the property `name` of `DataClassExample`. As the quote of the documentation you posted says: if you try this code, you will have an error.

```
open class SuperDataClass {
    open fun component1() {//<-- note this
        println("from super class")
    }
}

data class DataClassExample (var name: String): SuperDataClass() {
    //
}
```

The specific error is:

```
[DATA_CLASS_OVERRIDE_CONFLICT] Function 'component1' generated for the data class conflicts with member of supertype 'SuperDataClass'
```

Comment: About `componentN` functions, this explanation is not generally correct, (in this case yes) but they are really just used for destructuring of any type. Also, you might want to note that `component1` should be an `operator fun`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that, I wasn't too clear about it. but, in other hand, an `operator fun` must have a single parameter, `componentN` are just normal functions. These helps to generate the code for the destructuring declaration ([doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-declarations)).

Comment: That is not true, it is even in the documentation link you sent: "Note that the `componentN()` functions need to be marked with the `operator` keyword to allow using them in a destructuring declaration."

Comment: You are right, I'm mixing concepts, the data class auto-generates these operators. I don't know how to clarify this in order to the OP question. Feel free to add another answer pointing to that.